# Does the error "Table/View 'TABLE_1' already exists in Schema 'MYSCHEMA_1'" affect the application?

Tags: java, swing, derby

I have been working on an swing application using Netbeans and the database used is Derby.

In the development phase I have been using an implementation of Derby running in my local machine, this instance of derby is separated from the app.

At the moment I am trying to import the program in the production environment and I want the app to have a derby Db for each instance.

I am using a class that connects to the DB and creates few tables.
When the program is run for the first time the program runs fine, further runs obviously throw the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Table/View 'TABLE_1' already exists in Schema 'MYSCHEMA_1'.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at clienteditor.DerbyInitializer.main(DerbyInitializer.java:52)
at clienteditor.ClientEditor.main(ClientEditor.java:2224)
Caused by: ERROR X0Y32: Table/View 'TABLE_1' already exists in Schema 'MYSCHEMA_1'.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
```

My question is: considering that the app seams to works fine, does this error affect in any way my application ? It seams to me that it is bypassed and ignored.

thanks Alb

Comment: Whether this exception causes a problem for your application is up to your application. Throwing the exception doesn't cause a problem for Derby, but precisely how your application handles the exception is a different question, and depends on precisely what your application does when it receives the exception.

Comment: Hi Bryan, sorry for my late reply; so if my code looks like this, and the application does not crash, there should not be any problem                   try {
      stmt.execute("create table ....");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: That seems like a fine way to catch and ignore the table already exists exception. You could refine your code to catch a more specific exception, and to avoid the printStackTrace unless you receive an unexpected exception, but the overall technique should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

We recently started making our project compatible with hibernate 3 and 5 at same time tried refactoring and faced similar issue. We use Derby data base for local testing. I faced this issue when i am refactoring to get create query from hibernate session (for hibernate 5 as we cannot get connection from hibernate session  as we do with hibernate 3 ).

**The first suggestion** for this is to delete local derby folder for that specific project which gets create in your eclipse work space and try. 
If the problem still persists try check how you are writing query, if there is  way to refactor the code before you start running delete the existing derby for that project and then run the test.